# Artifacts in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

[image]
How do I get rid of the artifacts / distorted areas at the bottom of the wall. I have samples at 500 and light bounces at 50. Do I need more light in the scene? Any ideas? I do have the main light coming through a skylight / object with a glass shader if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi :) Those are denoiser artifacts. You need to increase the samples so Denoiser has more data to work with ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the sky lights transparent with a sun light coming through, I got rid of the sun light and had the windows emit the same color and equivalent strength of light. That way Blender doesn't have to work as hard on the lighting and denoising. I was able to reduce the render samples and still have clean lines.